# Image is not displaying in Symfony twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to display the image on page , my image directory path is `web/symfony/web/uploads/abcd.png` , any help would be appreciated..thanks

Comment: maybe a bit of your code of what isn't working could help ...

Comment: `<li class="list-group-item"><img src="{{ asset('/') }}"></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Category :{{ todo.category }}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Description :{{ todo.description}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Author :{{ todo.author}}</li>`

Comment: actually i''m storing book info , i.e name , author and image ,everything is working except image

Comment: asset in twig is relative to the web root so `{{ asset('uploads/abcd.png') }}` should be enough.

Comment: edit your post with the infos

Comment: its not working  here is the code `<img src="{{ asset('uploads/~ todo.image ') }}">`

Comment: try `<img src="{{ asset('uploads/' ~ todo.image) }}`

Comment: @ArtOsi answer looks correct assuming that todo.image contains the exact image that is in the uploads path only (ex. abcd.png)

Comment: {{ asset('symfony/web/uploads/abcd.png') }} , its worked for me , thanks artOsi for help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `{{ asset('symfony/web/uploads/abcd.png') }}`
You path must starting from `symfony_project/web` then path to you image 'symfony/web/uploads/abcd.png'.

Answer (score 1):

According to code you've pasted in comments it would be

```
<li class="list-group-item"><img src="{{ asset('uploads/' ~ todo.image) }}"></li> 
<li class="list-group-item">Category :{{ todo.category }}</li> 
<li class="list-group-item">Description :{{ todo.description}}</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Author :{{ todo.author}}</li>
```